# Play videos (with audio) under Python

Tags: python, windows, multimedia

I need to play several videos (with the relative audios) under a python script because I need to insert specific pauses between them and triggers (for a neuropsychological experiment).
I tried many examples on the internet to implement the media player, like this one from [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/), but I didn`t manage to compile the library MPlayer.

Finally I just need to have videos controlled by python, either using an external program or not. The critical part is to find a way to implement playvideo() in the following code

```
for pairs in Videos_paired_to_play:
    video1,video2 = pairs

    send_trigger(triggerType1)
    playvideo(video1[1] )
    make_a_pause(2)
    playvideo(video2[1])
    send_trigger(triggerType2)
    make_a_pause(20)
```

Ideally, I would need a way to play videos without destroying the window after having played them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows, you could tie into the windows media player COM object which will have a lot more options available to you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564035(v=vs.85).aspx

Alternatively, you could find another feature-complete player that exposes it's Interface to COM or python depending on OS. This would probably beat trying to hack your own, and the documentation would be there if you needed to extend or refactor it for other things